# why the button inside a table cell which is clicked is undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I can't explain why ehn i click a button inside a table cell and try to get rowID - i see that its undefined

Here is my code

```
@model Onion.Web.ViewModels.CategoryViewModel

<script>
    function btnEdit_Click()
    {

            var par = this.parentNode.parentNode;

            alert(par.id);


    }
</script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Button</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.lstCategoryLanguages)
    {
        <tr id='@item.CategoryLanguagesID'>
            <td>@item.Title</td>
            <td>@item.ShortDescription</td>
            <td><input type="button"  value="Edit" onclick='btnEdit_Click()' /></td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: What is undefined? the `par` or `par.id`?

Comment: parentNode - that means that par is undefined. The exception is that - it can't get parrentNode of undefined

Comment: this.parentNode is undefined !!!!

Comment: Can you work with jQuery?

Comment: you cant use parentnode with this you must use document.getElementById

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `this` returns the wrong context there.

Try passing `this` in the onclick event and use the parameter instead in your function:

```
onclick='btnEdit_Click(this)'
```

I think it would be even better to bind `@item.CategoryLanguagesID` a second time and pass that the function to get rid of the static `parentNode.parentNode` reference. What if your structure changes over time? You'd always have to modify the function too.

Comment: Actually - you're perfectly right.  And I can'explain why it's working!!

Comment: But why - in oncli property - this - belongs to the owner of the function, Btn_Click() method - it'owner is  the buttonelement not the window element

Comment: It is because `this` returns the window element instead of your button. And the window element does not have the `parentNode` property.

Comment: What do you mean with "oncli"?

Comment: You are right. But the owner of the function is not the button. You put the function into the global namespace/object which is the `window` object in this case. Just for the sake of completeness: It's a bad habbit to put all stuff into the global namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the function the element you want to refer to, and then in the function use that.

This works for me:

```
<script>
    function btnEdit_Click(elem)
    {

            var par = elem.parentNode.parentNode;

            alert(par.id);


    }
</script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Button</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.lstCategoryLanguages)
    {
        <tr id='@item.CategoryLanguagesID'>
            <td>@item.Title</td>
            <td>@item.ShortDescription</td>
            <td><input type="button"  value="Edit" onclick='btnEdit_Click(this)' /></td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```